# Apache Flink : Add side inputs for DataStream API

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-nifi, flink-streaming, flink-batch

In my **Java** application, I have **three DataStreams**. For example, for One stream data is consumed from Kafka, for another stream data is consumed from Apache Nifi. For these two streams Object type is different. For example, Stream-1 object type is Person, Stream-2 object type is Address.

The third one is the broadcast stream (for this data is consumed from Kafka).

Now I want to combine Stream-1 and Stream-2 in a Job class and want to split in the task process element. How to implement this?

**Note :** 
  Stream-1 is mainstream and Stream-2 is side input. MainStream is continuously fetching data from Kafka. For Side Input, initially while the application is UP all table data is loaded from DB and then read new data when the table data is updated (not frequently) .

**Sample structure:**

```
DataStream<Person> stream-1 = env.addSource(read data from kafka)....
DataStream<Address> stream-2 = env.addSource(read data from nifi)....
BroadcastStream<String> BroadCastStream = stream-3.broadcast(read data from kafka);
```

I was referred to as the following links.

[FLIP-17 Side Inputs for DataStream API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-17+Side+Inputs+for+DataStream+API#app-switcher)

[jira/browse/FLINK-6131](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6131)

**My Use case is :**

**Join stream with slowly evolving data:** The side input that we use for enriching is evolving over time (Data is read from DB). This can be done by waiting for some initial data to be available before processing the main input and the continuously ingesting new data into the internal side input structure as it arrives.

Comment: Could you update your question to why a join over the three sources is not sufficient? Also have a look at [temporal joins|https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table-function].

Comment: Join is not sufficient. Why because in my case each stream type is different. Join is applicable only for the same type of streams.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can easily join stream1 and stream2 even if they have different types. Then you can add the broadcast to the result.

Comment: Hi Arvid, Thanks for the details. Lets I will try.

Comment: Hi Arvid Heise,  I am new to the Flink. Do you have any sample code part for joining different stream type and broadcast?

Comment: [Joins in datastream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/joining.html) are used in [this example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/join/WindowJoin.java) and many more.

Comment: Thanks, Arvid Heise

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest response, the recommendation by @Arvid was in fact what was needed here.

Core of the answer:

> You can easily join stream1 and stream2 even if they have different
> types. Then you can add the broadcast to the result

Links to [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/stream/operators/joining.html) and [example](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/examples/join/WindowJoin.java), and a relevant snippet from the doc (the example is too long to be included in here):

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
 
...

DataStream<Integer> orangeStream = ...
DataStream<Integer> greenStream = ...

orangeStream.join(greenStream)
    .where(<KeySelector>)
    .equalTo(<KeySelector>)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
    .apply (new JoinFunction<Integer, Integer, String> (){
        @Override
        public String join(Integer first, Integer second) {
            return first + "," + second;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Dennis for your info. One doubt. In your example code block both orangestream and greenStream are the same Datatypes (both are Integer). If one is Integer and another one is a String type, can we able to apply to join() function?

Comment: @Azhagesan I can't check right now, but conceptually the keys need to 'fit' where the rest can be made together however you want. For instance the examples already show how you take two integers and make a string, I would expect it to be trivial to, for example: take an integer and a string and make a string. -- In the worst case you could explicitly cast the field to a different datatype.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis . Let me check